# Pandas, get first, second and third preferred authors for every user

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe of the form

```
 userID      author_cat  vote 
 234         1246        5.0
 121         2954        3.2
 234         1246        2.1
 121         2954        1.4
 234         1578        3.3
 234         1246        4.5
 121         2954        1.1
 121         9341        3.2
```

Expected

```
 userID      author_cat  vote  first_author     second_author   third_author
 234         1246        5.0   1246             1578            0
 121         2954        3.2   2954             9341            0
 234         1246        2.1   1246             1578            0
 121         2954        1.4   2954             9341            0
 234         1578        3.3   1246             1578            0
 234         1246        4.5   1246             1578            0
 121         2954        1.1   2954             9341            0
 121         9341        3.2   2954             9341            0
```

I want, for every user, to construct three columns, based on their ratings. The author that appears most (more books written by the same author, reviewed by one user) should appear in the "first_preferred_author" column (the categorical, like 1246). The same for the second and third preferred authors. If an author does not exist (either first, second and third, or even all three, the three new columns should contain 0).

So far I managed to get the order of appearance of the authors based on the number of reviews by the users, with:

```
df_new.groupby('userID')['author_cat'].value_counts()
```

but I don't know what to do from here.

EDIT:

The above command returns a `pd.series.series` (?) which looks like this (on a real dataset):

```
userID  author_cat
243     42994.0       6
        48986.0       5
        72473.0       3
        2505.0        2
        4371.0        2
        5270.0        2
        18764.0       2
        41267.0       2
        75183.0       2
        82066.0       2
        486.0         1
        571.0         1
        3507.0        1
        6343.0        1
        6524.0        1
        7530.0        1
        10539.0       1
        10679.0       1
        21123.0       1
        30948.0       1
        41305.0       1
        41479.0       1
        43715.0       1
        49236.0       1
        52183.0       1
        53204.0       1
        56812.0       1
        56916.0       1
        57911.0       1
        62266.0       1
                     ..
278633  54862.0       1
        57422.0       1
        66639.0       1
        72642.0       1
        72712.0       1
        73809.0       1
        82105.0       1
        87066.0       1
        91189.0       1
        93458.0       1
        94608.0       1
        96674.0       1
        99025.0       1
278843  80852.0       3
        3377.0        2
        4371.0        2
        2437.0        1
        2528.0        1
        5216.0        1
        18370.0       1
        30948.0       1
        35706.0       1
        37463.0       1
        40577.0       1
        62175.0       1
        62645.0       1
        81508.0       1
        92206.0       1
        92242.0       1
        93801.0       1
Name: author_cat, Length: 96302, dtype: int64
```

Comment: extend the dataframe to make atleast 5 rows and post the expexted output based on those 5 rows so we can understand better

Comment: @anky_91 done, basically group by user and thake the first three authors, by number of times seen.

Comment: Thanks for considering. :) upvoted

Comment: What do you want to do if multiple authors have the same number of appearence for the same userID?

Comment: @somiandras this is a tough one, I really don't know. I would say, add the first one on the list to preferred, second one to "second preferred" etc...even if they have the same number of appearances. I think for me, this would do the smallest harm. And if a user only voted for 1 author, the two other columns should be 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
(df.groupby(['userID']).author_cat
   .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.value_counts()
                               .nlargest(3).index))
   .unstack(level=1).fillna(0).astype(int))
```

Example (add one more row `121,2953,1.1` for an extra 3rd author):

```
userID,author_cat,vote
234,1246,5.0
121,2954,3.2
234,1246,2.1
121,2954,1.4
234,1578,3.3
234,1246,4.5
121,2954,1.1
121,9341,3.2
121,2953,1.1
```

Output:

```
+--------+------+------+------+
|        |  0   |  1   |  2   |
+--------+------+------+------+
| UserID |      |      |      |
+--------+------+------+------+
| 121    | 2954 | 9341 | 2953 |
| 234    | 1246 | 1578 |    0 |
+--------+------+------+------+
```

Comment: is it possible to make userID a regular column, so I can merge on it ?

Comment: A `reset_index()` at the end would help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about assigning the values for each column. But you can get back the top three authors for each user by using `nlargest` with `groupby`:

```
df.groupby('userID').author_cat.value_counts().groupby('userID').nlargest(3)

userID  author_cat
121     2954          3
        9341          1
234     1246          3
        1578          1
Name: author_cat, dtype: int64
```

Given your example `df` it looks the same as the original value counts, but if you ran this on your full dataset you would only get back the top 3 value counts for each userID.

Comment: Hi, Grr, this helps but I need to assign those values to the three columns.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of the following should work:

```py
preferences = (
    df
    .groupby(['userID', 'author_cat'])
    .size()
    .rename('count')
    .pipe(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x))
    .sort_values('count', ascending=False)
    .groupby('userID')
    .apply(lambda x: x.assign(rank=np.arange(len(x.index)) + 1)) # Adds incrementing rank even if counts are equal
    .reset_index()
    .set_index(['userID', 'rank'])
    ['author_cat']
    .unstack(1) # This "pivots" the dataframe
    .filter(lambda x: x <= 3, axis=1)
    .rename(columns={1: 'first_author', 2: 'second_author', 3: 'third_author'})
    .fillna(0)
    .astype('int')
)

df = df.join(preferences, on='userID')
```

I prefer `groupby().size()` over `value_counts()`, it gives similar results but retains index level names.

Also, pls note that this implementation does not pay attention to the ordering of `author_cat` if they have the same number of appearances for the same `userID`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution without using `apply`. Using `groupby.unique` to get a series of list of unique `author_cat` by order it appear. Unnesting it to dataframe. Assign 3 columns with values `0` to `df`. `set_index` on `df` to `userID`. Finally, `update` df from dataframe of `groupby.unique`:

```
d1 = df.groupby('userID')['author_cat'].unique()
d2 = pd.DataFrame(d1.tolist(), index=d1.index)

d2
Out[455]:
           0     1
userID
121     2954  9341
234     1246  1578
```

Final steps:

```
df[0], df[1], df[2] = 0, 0, 0
df.set_index('userID', inplace=True)
df.update(d2)

Out[456]:
        author_cat  vote       0       1  2
userID
234           1246   5.0  1246.0  1578.0  0
121           2954   3.2  2954.0  9341.0  0
234           1246   2.1  1246.0  1578.0  0
121           2954   1.4  2954.0  9341.0  0
234           1578   3.3  1246.0  1578.0  0
234           1246   4.5  1246.0  1578.0  0
121           2954   1.1  2954.0  9341.0  0
121           9341   3.2  2954.0  9341.0  0
```

Your sample has no third column values, so column `2` is still `0` after `update`.

If your data has third column values, the output gonna be like this(Note: *in this case, I added one row to your sample to demonstrate of third column*):

```
Out[462]:
        author_cat    vote     0     1       2
userID
234           1246     5.0  1246  1578     0.0
121           2954     3.2  2954  9341  9954.0
234           1246     2.1  1246  1578     0.0
121           2954     1.4  2954  9341  9954.0
234           1578     3.3  1246  1578     0.0
234           1246     4.5  1246  1578     0.0
121           2954     1.1  2954  9341  9954.0
121           9341     3.2  2954  9341  9954.0
121           9954  9954.0  2954  9341  9954.0
```